# How do I hide some of the questions in the Graphical Summary of Sharepoint 2013 Survey?

Tags: css, survey, cewp

Seems like this should be do-able using .css in a CEWP, with something like:

```
div [#h3.ms-standardheader, .ms-vb$="the next question"] {display: none;}

##h3.ms-standardheader, .ms-vb {display: none;}
```

will hide the text for all questions.  I just want to hide questions that end with "the next question" string.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors) you cant match content within an element.

**jQuery solution**

You could use the [:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector to get elements based on their content, the following example demonstrates how to hide question:

```
var q = $('h3.ms-standardheader,.ms-vb:contains("the next question")');
q.hide();  //hide question caption
q.next().hide(); //hide question results
```

**Update**

Use [.ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) to execute the code when a page is rendered:

```
$(function() {
   var q = $('#h3.ms-standardheader, .ms-vb:contains("the next question")'); 
   q.hide(); //hide question caption 
   q.next().hide(); //hide question results
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @vadim - I'm a newbie with jQuery.  I tried this in a CEWP, but it is not working.  Any suggestions?

<script>
     window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js">\x3C/script>');
</script>

<script>
var q = $('#h3.ms-standardheader, .ms-vb:contains("the next question")');
q.hide();  //hide question caption
q.next().hide(); //hide question results
</script>

Comment: @Quasimodo, the answer has been updated, basically the specified code need to be executed when a page is rendered